# Insert Oracle CLOB in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, clob

How do we use the CodeIgniter Framework to insert into a table that has a CLOB column?

Table is :

```
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATIONS
{
  ID NUMBER,
  CONTENT CLOB
}
```

The PHP Code is :

```
$id = 1;
$content = /* An Incredibly Long & Complex String */ 

$query = "INSERT INTO notifications (id,content) values (?,?)";
$this->dbconnxn->query($query, array($id,$content));
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: hey, did you managed to solve this problem. I am also trying to use nclob with codeigniter but it seems like CI doesnt support nclob, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't support this, you need to do it manually. In order to not re-create a connection to the database, you can use the connection ID created by CI:

```
$this->db->conn_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it creating in the model 2 functions 1) for insert and update the clob and 2) for read the clob:

1) In the model the function that I have created to set my Clob is updateClobImg64, it is called after the insert :

public function create_file($file){

```
    $file->file_pk1=$this->getMaxPk1();
    $data = array(
        "file_pk1" => $file->file_pk1,
        "file_name" => $file->file_name,
        "file_type"=>$file->file_type,
        "file_location"=>$file->file_location,
        //"file_img64"=>$file->file_img64,
        "file_created_date"=>$file->file_created_date,
        "file_created_by" => $file->file_created_by,
        "file_storage_type"=>$file->file_storage_type,

    );
    $this->db->insert("file_repository", $data);
    if(isset($file->file_img64) && !empty($file->file_img64)) $this->updateClobImg64($file->file_pk1,$file->file_img64);

    return $file->file_pk1;
}
```

public function updateClobImg64($file_pk1,$img64){

```
    $sql='update "file_repository" set "file_img64"=EMPTY_CLOB() where "file_pk1"='.$file_pk1.' RETURNING "file_img64" INTO :clob';

    $stid = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, $sql);
    $clob = oci_new_descriptor($this->db->conn_id, OCI_D_LOB);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":clob", $clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
    oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT); // use OCI_DEFAULT for PHP <= 5.3.1
    $clob->save($img64);

    oci_commit($this->db->conn_id);

    $clob->free();
    OCIFreeStatement($stid);


}</span>
```

2) To read the clob is is need a function read that I have implemented this way:
`function read_clob($field) {
        return $field->read($field->size());
    }`

and Is called in the model select funtion:

public function get_all(){

```
    $query = $this->db->get_where("file_repository", array());

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $files=$query->result();
        foreach($files as $key=>$row){

            $files[$key]->file_img64=$this->read_clob($row->file_img64);

        }

        return $files;
    }
}</span>
```

Hope this helps some one with this issue.